# Which JCE providers are FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Tags: java, cryptography, jce, fips

What Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) providers are FIPS 140-2 compliant? More specifically, does the Sun/Oracle provider qualify?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to this information on [this page](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm):

1. IBM and RSA have FIPS 140-2 validated JCE providers.
2. BouncyCastle have FIPS 140-2 validated JCE providers for Java 7 & 8.  (See [The Legion of the Bouncy Castle - FIPS Resources Page](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html).  Donations are encouraged!)
3. Sun's JCE providers are not on the list of FIPS 140-2 validated modules.

However, Oracle do have a validated module called "Oracle Cryptographic Libraries for SSL".  The description does not say this is a JCE provider ... but it might be.

Also, Oracle don't appear to have any "modules in progress" for FIPS 140-2 validation.

Comment: NIST provides a list on their website of validated modules.  RSA Security, Certicom, and Entrust all have validated JCE providers from what I recall.  Though they are **not** cheap!

Comment: URL seems outdated - maybe it's [here](https://csrc.nist.rip/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm) now?

Comment: It is the same document.

Comment: Can't tell, your .gov URL doesn't open here, while the .rip (? never seen one before) does. Might be our proxy though...

Answer (score 6):

According to  [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements.html), java 6 can be made FIPS 140 compliant via either NSS or SunJSSE.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [Sun PKCS#11 Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) does look like it is FIPS 140-2 compliant. It is based on [Network Security Services](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS). I'm pretty sure that is what certificates 1278, 1279 and 1280 are on that [NIST link](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm) that @stephen-c posted. The [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/FIPS.html) are a little vague regarding compliance but this is the best I have found so far.