# Does Eclipse Hono crypto comply with FIPS 140-2?

Tags: eclipse-hono

What crypto library does Eclipse Hono use by default and is it FIPS 140-2 validated. If not is there a way to build it with a crypto library that is?

Answer (score 0):

Hono uses the JRE's JCE provider for cryptography by default. However, it can also be configured to use native OpenSSL on Linux and OSX. I do not know whether any of these are FIPS 140-2 certified.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like [some JCE are FIPS validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046482/which-jce-providers-are-fips-140-2-compliant), also there is a [FIPS compliant OpenSSL implementation in the works](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_module_3.0)